# Search form not showing any results

Tags: php, mysql

I am making HTML/CSS search form using PHP and MySQL. IT doesn't display data I want. Not sure what I am doing wrong. I already have PHP working output for other options, it is just this search method is not finding any results. Been stuck for a while and decided to ask.

```
    if (isset($_POST["searchcrews"]))
  {
    $searchparam = "%{$_POST['search']}%";
    $stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM crewdata WHERE name LIKE ? AND is_approved =? ORDER BY (vote_up - vote_down) DESC LIMIT ?,?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$searchparam);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result=$stmt->get_result();

  }
```

HTML/CSS

```
    <form id="searchcrews">          
<div class="box">
  <div class="container-4">
    <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search crew.." />
   <button type="submit" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>

  </div>
</div>
          </form>
```

Comment: `name attribute` is missing in form and input type!!

Comment: `number of Placeholder is not equal to bind_param`

Comment: Take a look at your http servers error log file. That is where you can simply read what the issue is and where exactly. You cannot really develop php without monitoring that file. Unless you want to play endless guessing games.

Comment: fixed both issues and still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this hope it helps made some modification in form and button

```
 <form id="searchcrews" method="post">          
<div class="box">
  <div class="container-4">
    <input type="text" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search crew.." />
   <input type="submit" class="icon" name="searchcrews">

  </div>
</div>
          </form>
```

Comment: can you fix it with my submit button icon?

Comment: you can place icon in css file with some class and use it in button

Answer (score 1):

Add the 'name' attribute to your input tag and the method to the form tag.

```
<form id="searchcrews" method="POST">          
  <div class="box">
    <div class="container-4">
      <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search crew.." />
      <button type="submit" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: @swipeales What if you add the method attribute to the form tag?

Comment: always displays all results.

Comment: @swipeales What is the name of your input tag? It should be the same as the attribute name that you test in your if statement.